# Trouble connecting to nodes using truffle for Azure Blockchain Service

Tags: azure, blockchain, truffle, quorum, azure-blockchain-service

Unable to connect to transaction nodes for Azure Blockchain Service

I am trying to connect to transaction nodes, I've defined the connection strings in "truffle-config.js" as described in the example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain/service/send-transaction).

```
var alpha = "https://alpha-test.blockchain.azure.com:3200/***********";
var myAccount = "0x1B21e60D66a0598F95096c214Fe84c960f80fF89";
var myPassword = "*******";
alpha: {
      provider: new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(alpha),
      network_id: "*",
      gas: 0,
      gasPrice: 0
    }
```

whenever I execute the truffle console command to connect to alpha node, I am returned the following error:

```
$ truffle console --network alpha

Could not connect to your Ethereum client.
Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle-config.js)
```

whereas I am able to connect to both the defaultnode and beta node. I've tried hitting the rpc endpoints using browser and they seem to work. But I am unable to do so via truffle. Please help me out.

Comment: Maybe this could help https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider#general-usage

Comment: Thanks Zulhilmi, but Azure Blockchain Services come with their own hdwallet-provider I suppose.